# RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded. Expanded not working

Tags: flutter

I am using a `scrollable column` and `ListView.builder` inside the `column`. I have checked another answers in stackoverflow and wrapped the `ListView.builder` inside `Expanded` widget but still problem continue

> RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

```
List<String> items = [
    'item1',
    'item1',
    'item1',
    'item1',
    'item1',
    'item1',
    'item1',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text('Testing1'),
            SizedBox(height: 150),
            Text('Testing2'),
            SizedBox(height: 150),
            Text('Testing3'),
            SizedBox(height: 150),
            Text('Testing4'),
            SizedBox(height: 150),
            Text('Testing5'),
            SizedBox(height: 150),
            Text('Testing6'),
            SizedBox(height: 150),
            Text('Testing7'),
            SizedBox(height: 150),
            if (items.isNotEmpty)
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  
                  itemCount: items.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(items[index]),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Text('Testing1'),
      SizedBox(height: 150),
      Text('Testing2'),
      SizedBox(height: 150),
      Text('Testing3'),
      SizedBox(height: 150),
      Text('Testing4'),
      SizedBox(height: 150),
      Text('Testing5'),
      SizedBox(height: 150),
      Text('Testing6'),
      SizedBox(height: 150),
      Text('Testing7'),
      SizedBox(height: 150),
      if (items.isNotEmpty)
        ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: items.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(items[index]),
            );
          },
        ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Result Screen-> [image]

Comment: if i wrap  the column with Expanded and items is empty then column is not scrollable and overflow bottom error coming.

Comment: @Curious I have update my answer please check

Comment: ok working. Explanation would be highly appreciate.

Comment: Sure, as per my knowledge when we use SingleChildScrollView for column so dont use Expanded or Flexible widget inside column, and when we get this error-> non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded so declare shrinkWrap: true, inside Listview

Answer (score 0):

Try `shrinkWrap:true` inside the `ListView.builder`